# Using javascript/jQuery to populate a form field with database value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP form used to submit data. This form auto-populates fields based on a case number or "id" by querying a SQL database and retrieving more data to populate other fields based on the ID. I am tasked with adding a field, but I cannot get it to auto-populate. I tried reverse-engineering the other fields, but this thing is like a spider web.

The goal is to query for a  date field in the SQL DB, pull that date, and input it into the text field in the main form's #3. "PMV to MVA" input/text field.

I have redacted irrelevant code for simplicity's sake:

**recoveryForm.php** (the main form): User enters case number, and using the onblur="loadCase()" function, the fun begins..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Recovery Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="recoveryForm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="borderdiv"><div class="innerdiv">
            <h1>Recovery Template:</h1>
            <p>Date: <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?></p>
            <form action="submit_1.php" id="mainForm" method="post">
                <p>
                    <span class="qText" name="casenum"><b>Case Number: </b></span>
                    <input type="number" name="casenum_a" onblur="loadCase();" required>
                </p>
        <table class="mainTable" name="mainTable">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="qText" name="pmv_to_mva">3. PMV to MVA:</span></td>
                <td><span class="qAns" name="pmv_to_mva_a">No</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          <div class="submitDiv"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**recoveryForm.js:** which contains all of the JS functions

```
function loadCase(){
    getPMV();
    document.getElementsByName("casenum1_s")[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByName("casenum_a")[0].value;
    
function getPMV(){
    var myCasenum=document.getElementsByName("casenum_a")[0].value;
    window.alert(casenum_a);
    $.post(
        "getPMV.php",
        {casenum: myCasenum},
        function(data, status){ setPMV(data);}
    );
}

function setPMV(data){
    var jdata=JSON.parse(data);
    document.getElementsByName("pmv_to_mva_a")[0].value=jdata.ptm;
    document.getElementsByName("pmv_to_mva_a")[0].innerHTML=jdata.ptm;
}
```

And the **getPMV.php** file that's called from within the JS function:

```
<?php
    $success=FALSE;
    $postCasenum = getPostCasenum();
    #header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $sql = "select user_case_data.PMV_to_MVA from user_case_data WHERE casenum=?";
    $conn = odbc_connect( "needles","dba","sql" );
    if( $conn ) {
        echo $sql;
        $stmt=odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult=odbc_execute($stmt);

        if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt)) {
            $data = [
                'ptm' => odbc_result($stmt,1) ? "No" : "Yes"
            ];
            echo json_encode($data);

        odbc_close( $conn );
    } else {
        echo "{}";
    }
?>
<?php
    function getPostCasenum(){
        return $_POST["casenum"];
    }
?>
```

I know the SQL query is good and returns the date value I want to update onto the form. I put the javascript inline in the last code example on this page that can be used as an example (along with jquery file and getPMV.php). No matter what I try, the json response shows blank/empty for the pmv_to_mva field, when I know that field does indeed contain data.

Anybody might be able to point me in the right direction here? Thank you.

========================== EDIT =================================

I continued to get "loadCase is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onblur", so I reasoned that there still must be some syntax error with my javascript. I decided to move the script inline to see if I could make any progress.

"Uncaught reference error: casenum_a is not defined at getPMV"...

recoveryform.php (line 16):

```
<input type="number" name="casenum_a" onblur="loadCase();" required>
```

recoveryForm.php in it's entirety:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Recovery Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="recoveryForm.js"></script>-->

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadCase(){
            getPMV();

        function getPMV(){
            var myCasenum=document.getElementsByName("casenum_a")[0].value;
            console.log(casenum_a);
            $.post(
                "getPMV.php",
                {casenum: myCasenum},
                function(data){ setPMV(data);}
            );}

        function setPMV(data){
            console.log(data);
            var jdata=JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementsByName("pmv_to_mva_a")[0].innerHTML=jdata.ptm;
            }
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="borderdiv"><div class="innerdiv">
            <h1>Recovery Template:</h1>
            <p>Date: <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?></p>
            <form action="submit_1.php" id="mainForm" method="post">
                <p>
                    <span class="qText" name="casenum"><b>Case Number: </b></span>
                    <input type="number" name="casenum_a" onblur="loadCase();" required>
                </p>
        <table class="mainTable" name="mainTable">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="qText" name="pmv_to_mva">3. PMV to MVA:</span></td>
                <td><span class="qAns" name="pmv_to_mva_a">No</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          <div class="submitDiv"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's devtools, the network tab and console tab? Network tab would show an ajax call firing off and what raw data it gets back. The console would show you any js errors and crashes (because jshint.com notes some syntax issues).

Comment: You might not need `var jdata=JSON.parse(data);` as `$.post` without options should auto-detect the json return (if php did its thing right) and auto-parse it into `data`. You can pepper your javascript with `console.log( data );` and `console.log('setPMV called');` and the sort to see what happens at each step of js code.

Comment: Your `loadCase` function is missing its closing `}`. Check your browser console for errors

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("pmv_to_mva_a")[0].value=jdata.ptm` does nothing useful, since `<span class="qAns" name="pmv_to_mva_a">No</span>` is not an `<input>` field. Keep the following line, which properly sets the `innerHTML` property of that element.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the information-  I will check all of the above at work tomorrow (don't have access atm) and report back. Again I truly appreciate all of your time and suggestions.

Comment: @kmoser the reason that line exists is becayse the <span> line once was an input field. Many of the other fields include both "document.getElementsByName("pmv_to_mva_a")[0].value=jdata.ptm" and the next line. I tried switching the tags around to try to get results but did not get anything. Should it matter that it's not an input line? Would I benefit by switching it back to <input> rather than <span>? Sorry if these are newb-like questions.

Comment: @invokePrejudice It's one or the other: if it's an `<input>` field, it has a `.value` property (which the user can change). If it's a `<span>`, it has a `.innerHTML` property. It's up to you to decide which is better.

Comment: FYI, the `echo $sql;` in **getPMV.php** will corrupt the JSON that is returned below. You should comment out that statement except for debugging.

Comment: @kmoser thanks, I commented out the echo sql. When I look at the json data being returned, simply nothing is there... as if it's null. But when I run the query in sql editor, I get the result. So something is broken between the sql statement and the data being returned

Comment: This line should **not** be commented out: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @kmoser please see the edit I made at the bottom of my post. Still getting errors in the console for some reason.

Comment: You'll have to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably by editing your original question.

Comment: @kmoser I'm doing my best to follow the rules and guidelines for making (and keeping) this a quality post. I did modify my original question with my update. Regarding the reproducable example, to reproduce, you would need a database with a table "user_case_data" and 2 columns "casenum" and "pmv_to_mva". Populate with a row containing any case number, and any date in the pmv_to_mva column. When user types that case number into the field, onblur I am trying to show the date on the form contained in the pmv_to_mva column.

Comment: @invokePrejudice Fair enough, I see what you mean. In any case, it looks like in **recoveryForm.js**, `function loadCase()` is missing its closing `}`, which should come right before `function getPMV()`.

Comment: In your query, you're not utilizing `$postCasenum` anywhere. As a test, in that file you can change `return $_POST["casenum"];` to `return $_GET["casenum"];` and then you can visit this php page directly like http://localhost/getPMV.php?casenum=33 to test your PHP script without the JS interaction. After `$queryResult=odbc_execute($stmt);` do `var_dump($queryResult); die();` (or `var_dump(odbc_fetch_row($stmt))`) to see what that value is. You can change the parameter from 33 to whatever else you need to test. Once that's confirmed working you can be sure the issue is with your JS somewhere.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones as I began to suspect when running through the js with console.log(vars) to confirm things were working, my problem is with the getPMV.php file. It just returns a 500 internal server error. At least I'm getting closer!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for all of your help and suggestions. I was able to accomplish what I was after. My problem was somewhere in my getPMV.php file. I found success in simplifying the file. This worked:

```
<?php
    $success=FALSE;
    $postCasenum = getPostCasenum();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $sql = "select user_case_data.PMV_to_MVA from user_case_data WHERE casenum=?";
    $conn = odbc_connect( "needles","dba","sql" );
    if( $conn ) {
        #echo $sql;
        $stmt=odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult=odbc_execute($stmt, array($postCasenum));
        $json='{';
        while(odbc_fetch_row($stmt)){
            $json=$json.'"ptm":"'.odbc_result($stmt,1).'"';
        }
        $json=$json.'}';
        echo $json;
        odbc_close( $conn );
    } else {
        echo "{}";
    }
?>
<?php
    function getPostCasenum(){
        return $_POST["casenum"];
    }
?>
```